# Developing GWT under Tomcat?

Tags: java, spring, gwt, tomcat, servlets

Is it possible to run GWT in hosted mode under Tomcat, not Jetty in Eclipse? I am going to integrate GWT widgets into spring app, so it make requests to spring controllers. But developing, spring is ran on one server, GWT on another... So I can't make direct requests to spring controllers, and I am tired of doing monkey work, writing servlets under jetty which make requests to spring controllers under tomcat...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use Tomcat instead of Jetty. You should start devmode with -noServer flag..
Here is more explanation from [gwt web site](http://code.google.com/webtoolkit/doc/latest/DevGuideCompilingAndDebugging.html#How_do_I_use_EJBs_in_development_mode?)